# Probability mass function, a proof of the basic property.

Tags: probability-theory

#### Lemma

The probability mass function $f:\mathbb{R}\to[0,1]$ satisfies, the set of $x$ such that$f(x)\ne0$ is countable.

Could you help me to prove it? The textbook does not provide any proof or hint. It only says that the proof is obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of
$$A_n:=\{x: f(x)>1/n\} \implies \{x: f(x)\neq 0\}=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} A_n $$

it is enough to show that the $A_n$ are finite. Since countable unions of countable sets are countable.

Now assume that $A_n$ is infinite. So I can find a sequence $x_i \subset A_n$ of distinct points. Thus:
$$P(A_n)\ge P\left(\biguplus_{i\in\mathbb{N}} \{x_i\}\right) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty P(\{x_i\})= \sum_{i=1}^\infty f(x_i)>\sum_{i=1}^\infty 1/n = \infty$$

Which is a contradiction.

In words: The number events with probability above $1/n$ is finite. By placing these sets of events after each other it becomes obvious that I can count through all events which have positive probability.

Comment: Does it mean that the set of $x$ not only countable, but also finite? In the second part you assumed that $A_n$ is infinite, then you chose a sequence of $x_i$ out of $A_n$, finally you showed that under our assumptions $P(A_n) >\inf$ , which is obviously a contradiction, thus $A_n$ is finite.

Comment: each individual $A_n$ is finite. But they get bigger over n. I mean the number of events with probability $1/n$ is smaller than the number of events with probability at least $1/(n+1)$ and the union of all these events could still be countable. And this union is the set of events with strictly positive probability. E.g. the geometric distribution, where $P(n)=(1-p)^{k-1}p$  i.e. all natural numbers have positive probability (infinite set) but the set of points with probability greater $1/m$ is finite

Comment: Ok, I think I understood. Thank you.